# Convergence of image reconstruction using genetic algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, genetic-algorithm, convergence

I'm implementing an image reconstruction method using genetic algorithm (for optimization). I randomly opted 10 population(each population is an image with intensity values in row major order) as follows

```
for i = 1:population_size
   eval(['population_' num2str(i) '= (randi([MinIntensity,MaxIntensity],1,No_of_Individuals))']);
end
```

My question is, can I choose the initial population similar to the image (i.e. the reconstructed image) does the genetic algorithm will converge quickly? If yes, how to initialize the population similar to the reconstructed image (assume that I have a reconstructed image with me).

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question but there is [no need to use `eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) here. You can use a [multi-dimensional array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html), a [data structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) (e.g. `mydata.population(i)`), or [dynamic field references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/).

Comment: You should really review your question. It is hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: @Steffen Editted the question.Kindly go through it.